# Why does Angular FormControl set 'disabled' in DOM but not 'required'?

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular4-forms

I've moved my form logic from the template into FormGroup & FormControl objects. When I disable a FormControl Angular also updates the `disabled` attribute for the field in the DOM. However, when I update the control's validators to include/exclude `Validators.required` the `required` attribute is NOT updated in the DOM.

Just wondering why this is? I need both set, otherwise Angular Material does not style the field with an '*' telling the user that it is required.

Answer (score 0):

They do mention a little tidbit in their documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#built-in-validators)

I think basically, it wasn't something that they needed to make reactive forms work. It's independent of the html. They say "The required attribute is still present. While it's not necessary for validation purposes, you may want to keep it in your template for CSS styling or accessibility reasons."

I remember seeing somewhere that they were planning to eventually have the Validators.required reactive configuration also update the required html attribute for you, but just haven't got it coded yet.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but isn't that all true for the `disabled` attribute as well (it's not necessary for validation)? So it's simply of matter of: they've implemented for `disabled` but haven't got round to `required` yet...

Comment: I bet disabled is a lot more important to the implementation. I think they are probably using the html/browser features to prevent someone from clicking a disabled button. Required on the other hand they are not using html5 validation for sure. They are using javascript code to check if the field has an entry or not. So maybe thats why they can put off required but not disabled